# Batch file scripting

Tags: windows, scripting, batch-file

My Application.exe takes a filename as a parameter.

I would like to write a windows batch file script that does the following:

Lets me point to a folderpath and does the following:

```
 for int = 0 ; i<folderpath.filecount();i++
{
  Application.exe filename[i]
}
```

Many Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the `for` command.  For example (FIXED)

```
for %%i in (%1\*) do Application.exe "%%i"
```

see `help for` for lots of extra useful options and syntax.

Comment: Error: '/*) was unexpected at this time' ..need a bit more help on this...or am i being dense?

Comment: @evil otto: Seems like you've mixed up the `%`/`%%` usage. It should be `%%i` (both of them) and `%1`. And to play safe, it might be better to use `\ ` as the path delimiter. One other thing: the second occurrence of `%%i` might need to be enclosed in double quotes.

Comment: So... for %%i in (%1\*) do Application.exe %%i or for %%i in (%1\*) do Application.exe "%%i"

Comment: @Andriy M - you're completely right; serves me right for writing it from memory.

Comment: @van: Yes, @​evil otto has been good enough to amend his solution, so you can use it for reference.